# Git Line Endings problem on a Windows shared volume with a Unix docker container

Tags: windows, git, docker, unix, line-endings

I'm working on Windows and use centOS docker containers for my development. I also have a volume shared between my containers and a local folder.

The problem is: when cloning a repository from windows into the shared volume or from the container into the shared volume, a `git status` does not return the same thing when it is executed in the container and on the local machine. I expect it to be the same and tried different configurations without success:

- `git config --global core.autocrlf true/input/false` on the local machine and in the container
- `git config --global core.crlf true/false/auto` on the local machine and in the container
- `git config --global core.eol lf` ...

Does anyone have the right configuration of Git to get an identical `git status` from the container and on the local machine without modifying the .gitattributes?

Comment: Sharing a repository across OSes is necessarily going to involve `git status` re-reading every file, even if you fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to configure line endings is:

On Linux:

```sh
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

On Windows:

```sh
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

You can also set repository-specific configurations:

```sh
cd /path/to/repo
git config core.autocrtlf <value>
```

In your situation, it sounds that if you set `git config --global core.autocrlf input` in your CentOS containers and `git config --global core.autocrlf true` for your Windows machine, you shouldn't have issues.

Comment: I set options but I still get different results after: `git clone && git status`. I assume "red files" are files with wrong line endings. So I don't understand why they are modified. Perhaps wrong configuration ? :/

Comment: Did you set the options exactly as I suggest?

Comment: Yes exactly. To be sure I deleted everything that could interfere with both configuration and ran yours. Then, I cloned the repository into the centOS container and git status, everything is good. Back on windows, `git status` in the volume shared with the container and some files are red. They are binaries so I assume their were modified by git but I expect it to not be the case. One way would be to modify the .gitattributes but I cannot.

Comment: Oh! They are binaries! That changes everything. You didn't mention this in your question. Binaries are OS dependant. So this is not a line ending issue and there is nothing you can do about it in Git settings.

Comment: Though, you are not generating the binaries in different OSes... you are simply cloning... I don't know. Using Git for binaries is a bit outside of the mainstream Git usage. So I am not sure what is going on. But I am not sure your question really reflects your problem.

Comment: Text files in different OSes have different line endings and Git (built for text files) can handle this. Moving binaries between OSes may introduce similar small changes that Git (not built for binaries) is not capable of handling.

Comment: Also, note that Git has a heuristic for detecting binaries. And it shouldn't apply the line ending config to those files. But maybe your files are not detected as binaries and Git is applying some line ending config to them. You can try removing all your line ending config or make sure that your files [are recognized by Git as binaries](https://bluishcoder.co.nz/2007/09/06/git-binary-files-and-cherry-picking.html).

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the lack of details and thank you, you partially answered my problem. Only those binaries remain red. I need to keep them versionned because they are difficult to find out there. Also, not all binaries are affected, only 3 of them and I think the only solution is to work with WSL on windows to avoid this, or to work with the .gitattributes which I cannot modify :(.

Comment: Thus, from git-config man page: "Unfortunately, the desired effect of cleaning up text files with mixed line endings and the undesired effect of corrupting binary files cannot be distinguished", So yeah, I'll work with WSL until the .gitattributes can be modified. I'll mark your post as an answer. Thank you for your time !